# Prolog checking if two lists are identical

Tags: prolog

So I need to write a prolog term called `doubleAll7/2` that takes two lists. The program returns true if for every 7 that occurs in the first list, the second list has two sevens in a row.
Example `doubleAll7([1,7,1],[1,7,7,1])` is true but `doubleAll7([1,2,7],[1,2,7])` is false.

`double7/2` doubles all occurrences of 7 in a list and works perfectly.

For some reason this program always returns false.

```
    doubleAll7([H1|T1],[H2,T2]) :-
    double7([H1|T1], L),
        L == [H2|T2].

    double7([],[]).
    double7([H|T], [H,H|Z]) :-
    H is 7,
    !,
    double7(T,Z).
    double7([H|T], [H|Z]) :-
    double7(T,Z).
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an obvious error: the first row

```
doubleAll7([H1|T1],[H2,T2])
```

should be

```
doubleAll7([H1|T1],[H2|T2])
```

I mean: a `|` instead a `,` as separator between `H2` and `T2`

But, sorry: I find you solution overcomplicated.

You can avoid `double7/2` (your call to `double7` is unusefull because, if I'm not wrong, it's equivalent to

```
doubleAll7(L1, L2) :-
  double7(L1, L2).
```

), you can avoid `is/2`, you can avoi the `!` and you can semplify all as

```
doubleAll7([], []).

doubleAll7([7 | T1], [7, 7 | T2]) :-
  doubleAll7(T1, T2).

doubleAll7([H | T1], [H | T2]) :-
  H \== 7,
  doubleAll7(T1, T2).
```

Comment: Oh jeez that fixed it...  had made that error several times before and when I fixed it didn't work. Must have unfixed it again and been unable to tell when I got it right

Comment: @user237083 - I know... I'm an expert doing this type of errors.